# Save Animation via Python Script in ParaView

Tags: python, animation, paraview

I am trying to save an `.avi` animation in ParaView via python script. The script I wrote works, nonetheless, the animation corresponds to a steady frame. What should I change in order to obtain an animation with all 10 frames from my ParaView model?

Here is my script (movie.py):

```
from paraview.simple import *
movie = servermanager.animation.AnimationScene()
movie.ViewModules = [GetActiveView()]
movie.NumberOfFrames = 10
movie_writer = servermanager.vtkSMAnimationSceneImageWriter()
movie_writer.SetFileName("/Users/wbr/Desktop/movie.avi")
movie_writer.SetFrameRate(1)
movie_writer.SetQuality(2)
movie_writer.SetAnimationScene(movie.SMProxy)
movie_writer.Save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ParaView 4.2 (RC1), this is the script I get when I generate a Python trace for the action of saving an animation.

```
#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *

# save animation images/movie
WriteAnimation('/tmp/movie.ogv', Magnification=1, FrameRate=15.0, Compression=True)
```

Comment: How do you trace actions on ParaView? I am currently trying to select points programmatically and plot them over time. I got some hints from .psvm (state files), but it only works if the point ID is known. In my case, I am trying to select a point based on coordinates.

Comment: Open paraview > Tools > Start Trace > Accept Defaults > Do what you need to do > Stop Trace > Investigate code in script editor

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found to export an ParaView Animation programmatically:

```
reader = GetActiveSource()
view = GetActiveView()
AnimateReader(reader,view,filename="../movie.avi")
```

The only problem is that I cannot set the Frame rate. Any suggestions?

Comment: Or even better (easier): paraview.simple.WriteAnimation(filename, **params), check: http://www.paraview.org/ParaView3/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/paraview.simple.html

Answer (score 0):

Latest version (Movie with white background):

```
from paraview.simple import *
viewModel = GetActiveView()
viewModel.Background = [1,1,1]
Show()
Render()
paraview.simple.WriteAnimation(filename="/Users/wilsondasilva/Desktop/movie.avi",FrameRate=15.0)
```